# Retry post/get requests on error and complete original success/error callbacks

Tags: angularjs, http, post, get, interceptor

We have an application that requires users to be logged in. Once logged in the user interacts with web api. Our issue is when the authentication expires we want to show a Login page, for the user to log back in without being redirected. This way they will not lose there work. Our issue is as follows:

**Inside our Controller an request is made**

```
$http.get("/api/Document/GetDocumentsManage").success(function (response) {
       $scope.Documents = response;
});
```

On the server we identify that the user is no longer authenticated and we reject the call. We then use an interceptor to catch the error and handle it to show a popup modal.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $injector) {

    return {
        'responseError': function (rejection) {

            var response = rejection;
            var defer = $q.defer();

            if (rejection.status == 401 || rejection.status == 400) {

                var modal = $injector.get("$mdDialog");
                modal.show({
                    parent: angular.element("body"),
                    targetEvent: window.event,
                    templateUrl: "/directives/LoginPage/Login.html",
                    controller: "loginController",
                    onRemoving: function () {

                        var $http = $injector.get("$http");
                        $http(rejection.config);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    };
});
```

With this code we can successfully re-authenticate without the user navigating away from the page, and then once authenticated again we can execute the original request. Our issue is the resubmitted request is not bound to the original .success callback of our request. Therefore in this example $scope.Documents does not get set to the response. Is there anyway we can rerun any request that failed and continue execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track! You just need a few minor changes to ensure that the result makes in back to your controller:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $injector) {

    return {
        'responseError': function (rejection) {

            var response = rejection;
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var $http = $injector.get("$http");  //moved this for readability
            var modal = $injector.get("$mdDialog"); //moved this for readability

            if (rejection.status == 401 || rejection.status == 400) {

                modal.show({
                    parent: angular.element("body"),
                    targetEvent: window.event,
                    templateUrl: "/directives/LoginPage/Login.html",
                    controller: "loginController",
                    onRemoving: function () {
                        // resolve the deferred
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });

                // return the promise object
                return deferred.promise.then(function() {
                  // return the new request promise
                  return $http(rejection.config);
                });
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Take a look at the is blog example where they are doing the same thing you are trying to do: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/#sessionrecovererresponseerrorinterceptor

Comment: Perfect! this was what i needed